# Keep window always on top?

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow

In Objective-C for Cocoa Apps it's possible to use such way to keep window always on top?

How to achieve the same with Swift?

```
self.view.window?.level = NSFloatingWindowLevel
```

Causes build error `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSFloatingWindowLevel'`

Comment: The link is no longer available.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

To change the window level you can't do it inside viewDidload because view's window property will always be nil there but it can be done overriding viewDidAppear method or any other method that runs after view is installed in a window (do not use it inside viewDidLoad):

**Swift 4 or later**

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    view.window?.level = .floating
}
```

For older Swift syntax check the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27397096/revisions) history

Comment: Where exactly that line should go?

Comment: @LeoDabus  Why do I get the error: 'Int' is not convertible to 'CGWindowLevelKey'?

Comment: Breaks in swift 2.0. Any way arounds?

Comment: When set it to .FloatingWindowLevelKey or .MaximumWindowLevelKey, the window stays on top of full screen video, e.g. full screen YouTube video on Chrome, or VLC in full screen mode. This is not exactly what I want. Do you know the correct key which makes it float on top of other windows but below full screen videos?

Comment: @LeoDabus Should be above all apps and windows, not just mine. I've been trying different values of the CGWindowLevelKey enum but I'm starting to think there is no one liner to fix this unfortunately, as I just realized same thing also happens with the iTunes MiniPlayer's always on top option. It's probably because Chrome and VLC claim full screen in an unorthodox way, rather than the regular "full screen as a separate desktop" behavior of maximized Finder windows, or Safari's full screen mode for videos. (both of which do not expose this glitch) I'm open to any suggestions though.

Comment: @LeoDabus I did, along with many other values of the same enum to no avail. It looks like those applications in full screen are still somehow considered regular windows by the system. Will write here if I find a solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @sam try `Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(Int32(kCGMaximumWindowLevelKey)))`

Comment: @LeoDabus This gives me 'CGWindowLevelKey.Type' does not have a member named 'MaximumWindowLevelKey'

Comment: could you please help me, I need set button on the top of view stack. There is my case. I work with camera and camera dynamically set outputs in custom view , and such way override my static button... I need put my button on the top of camera preview to make it visible to user. Did you get my idea?

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer this way. This ignores all other active apps, and makes your app upfront.

```
    override func viewWillAppear() {            
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
    }
```

Comment: This will not _keep_ the window _always on top_, will it?

Answer (score 3):

While the other answers are technically correct - when your app will or did resigns active, setting the `window` level to `.floating` will have no effect.

`.floating` means on top of all the windows from the app you are working on, it means not on top of all apps windows.

Yes there are other levels available you could set, like *kCGDesktopWindowLevel* which you can and should not set in swift to make your window float above all.

None of them will change the fact that your window will go behind the focused and active apps window. To circumvent i chose to observe if the app resigns active notification and act accordingly.

```
var observer : Any;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        forName: NSApplication.didResignActiveNotification, 
        object: nil, 
        queue: OperationQueue.main ) { (note) in

        self.view.window?.level = .floating;

        // you can also make your users hate you, to take care, don't use them.
        //NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        //self.view.window?.orderFrontRegardless();
    }
}
```

another way could be subclassing NSWindow and override the property .level with an always returning .floating, but the code above is less work and keeps control in the place where you want to set the window floating.

Answer (score 3):

I spent a long time trying to make this work. I then realized there was a simple answer, just worded in a different way. Here it is: [Change macOS window level with SwiftUI (to make a floating window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619671/change-macos-window-level-with-swiftui-to-make-a-floating-window)

As explained there:

> You can access your windows with NSApplication.shared.windows and set the level for each one.

```swift
    for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
        window.level = .floating
    }
```

EDIT: you can use other levels, including `.screenSaver` (highest, I think) and ```.normal`` if you want to return to standard behavior. Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/level