# Window level for menu bar app

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am working on `Menubar` Mac app, using `Xcode 6.1.1` on `OSX 10.10.2`

How do I bring a child view controller NSWindow(like about window of app) at a level so that it is available **above** menubars popover view ?

I have tried setting all the levels available in  NSWindow selector using

```
 - (void)setLevel:(NSWindowLevel)level
```

but it is not working.

Comment: You can put that window as Modal Window. Please use NSApp runModalForWindow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396957/keep-window-always-on-top-cocoa-swift/27397096#27397096