# Set browserWindow Always on top, even other app is in fullscreen [Electron, MAC OS]

Tags: macos, window, electron

it's possible to use custom window level in Electron Framework, for make window always on top, even other apps is in fullscreen ?

For native MacOS apps i found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27397096/5838242

Where he saying:

```
window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGMaximumWindowLevelKey))
```

On electron, i have a browser window:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1400, height: 50, resizable: false, alwaysOnTop: true, y: 0, x: 0, minimizable: false, title: 'CD App', frame: false, titleBarStyle: 'hidden', type: 'desktop' });
```

I know the 'type' parameter is the POINT, but this parameter have just two options:

> On macOS, possible types are desktop, textured.
>   The textured type adds metal gradient appearance (NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask).
>   The desktop type places the window at the desktop background window level (kCGDesktopWindowLevel - 1). Note that desktop window will not receive focus, keyboard or mouse events, but you can use globalShortcut to receive input sparingly.

So, any possibilities to do this thing ?

Comment: Hi @Paulo Rodrigues, were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 30):

As of Electron 1.4.2 the [`setAlwaysOnTop()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winsetalwaysontopflag-level) API takes an optional `level` parameter to adjust the window level, you'd use it like so:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ ... });
mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'screen');
```

See the docs for all the possible values of the optional parameter, I'm not sure `screen` is the one you want in this case, you'll need to experiment.

Comment: This, answer my question partially, i need to know if is possible to do electron apps with highest window level possible, even if other apps (like keynote) is on fullscreen, i need to show a "toolbar" in front of keynote.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, you'll have to experiment.

Comment: works for me too, and also adding these to it, the app rules the screen```windowName.setMinimizable(false); fullscreen:true```

Answer (score 1):

2024 answer. You can do the following to have your window over everything including full-screen apps and across every workspace.

```js
  mainWindow.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true, { visibleOnFullScreen: true });
  mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'screen-saver', 1);
```

This [GH thread](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10078) follows a lot of the window on-top of full-screen feature creation/implementation.