# Change macOS window level with SwiftUI (to make a floating window)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nswindow

Hi is there a way to change the [window level](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/level) with SwiftUI so I can make a floating window for my mac app? I am using the SwiftUI life cycle

Answer (score 10):

You can access your windows with `NSApplication.shared.windows` and set the `level` for each one.

For instance:

```swift
Button("Float windows") {
    for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
        window.level = .floating
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window.level = .floating as Alexander Sandberg put, but you likely will only want to specify this for one window not every one in your app.

That said, take a look at Asperi's post that shows you how to access a window in macOS in SwiftUI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439982/10844710

I will summarize the pertinent code here:

```
#if os(macOS)
import SwiftUI
import AppKit

struct WindowAccessor: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var window: NSWindow?

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window = view.window
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}
#endif
```

You then can use it in a window group at the top level of your app like so:

```
ContentView().background(WindowAccessor(window: $window)).onChange(of: window) { newWindow in
    if windowFloats {
        newWindow?.level = .floating
    } else {
        newWindow?.level = .normal
    }
}.onChange(of: windowFloats) { floats in
    if windowFloats {
        window?.level = .floating
    } else {
        window?.level = .normal
    }
}
```

You can include your variables as needed:

```
#if os(macOS)
@State var window: NSWindow?
@AppStorage("windowFloats") private var windowFloats: Bool = false
#endif
```