# How to make a SwiftUI view "Always on top"?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to the XCode/SwiftUI scene and have a beginners question.

How can I tell SwiftUI to make a view "Always on top"?

I have a view with two buttons in it:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Button("Button1") {}
            .padding(20)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 40)
            
            Button("x") {
                NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil)
            }
            .padding(10)
            .frame(width: 70, height: 40)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which view and relative to which views "on top"?

Comment: You should rephrase :  «always in front»

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619671/change-macos-window-level-with-swiftui-to-make-a-floating-window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change macOS window level with SwiftUI (to make a floating window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619671/change-macos-window-level-with-swiftui-to-make-a-floating-window)

Answer (score 0):

First, here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack { // I put everything in this VStack (vertical stack)
            HStack{
                Button("Button1") {}
                .padding(20)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 40)
                
                Button("x") {
                    //
                }
                .padding(10)
                .frame(width: 70, height: 40)
            }
            
            Spacer() // I added this spacer at the bottom to push everything to the top
        }
    }
}
```

> Explanation

**What is a VStack?**

A VStack is a view that arranges its children in a vertical line.

**What is a Spacer?**

Spacer views automatically fill up all available space on their axis of expansion, which is a fancy way of saying they take up as much space as they can either horizontally or vertically, depending on what you put them in.

**So basically:**

When we put the HStack (horizontal stack) inside the VStack and add the `Spacer()` function at the bottom we push the HStack all the way to the top of the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! But what I want to achieve is that the running application window is on top of all other windows in macOS. Something like NSWindow.orderFrontRegardless() ? But don't know how to implement it..

Comment: Maybe you could try using a  ZSstack? if you have any further code you can share that'll help me help you :)

Comment: Thanks! Will ZStack make the macOS app float above all other apps?